# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCCManager"

Tags: xcode, react-native

This error happen but when I upgraded to 0.55.4 still exist.

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nick/Library./Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/bioreact-fmazebcdwsflmwcjcomjfrqlztce/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React'
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCCManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

you can find screenshot of error:
console:

[image]

Xcode:

[image]

output of react-native info:

```
Environment:
  OS: macOS Sierra 10.12.6
  Node: 8.9.4
  Yarn: 1.7.0
  npm: 5.6.0
  Watchman: 4.9.0
  Xcode: Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
  Android Studio: 3.0 AI-171.4443003
Packages: (wanted => installed)
  react: 16.2.0 => 16.2.0
  react-native: 0.53.0 => 0.53.0
```

Comment: I suggest that you start with the directory not found issue. Resolving that is also likely to fix the missing symbol problem.

Comment: @PaulFloyd which one Xcode or console ?

Comment: @nick did you resolve the issue ? i am facing the same probleme currently!

Comment: upgrade react native core, remove android and ios and node_modules folder. and start again from ground up